# XmlPullParserException: invalid drawable tag vector

Tags: android, vector, gradle, android-ndk, compatibility

I am using NDK support and getting this error:

Gradle:

Distribution: `gradle-2.5-all`

Build tool: `gradle-experimental:0.2.1`

XML:

```
    <vector android:height="24dp" android:viewportHeight="125.0"
android:viewportWidth="100.0" android:width="24dp" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<path android:fillColor="#FF000000" android:pathData="M97.01,-2.98,-3C47.02,95.35"/>
</vector>
```

Warning:

> vector requires API level 21 (current min is 13) or building with
>   Android Gradle plugin 1.4 or higher

Exception:

```
  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/accelerometer.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020045
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2842)
 at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:1521)

...
Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #1: invalid drawable tag vector
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:917)
 at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:858)
```

Comment: https://github.com/wnafee/vector-compat/issues/15

Comment: did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

On pre-Lollipop devices you need to use VectorDrawableCompat to get your vector from resources.

```
 someVectorDrawable = VectorDrawableCompat.create(context.getResources(), R.drawable.[some res id], null);
```

Then you can set your ImageView's background.

Comment: I am getting this error with buildToolsVersion "25.0.3" for api 19 when using drawableLeft on a button.  This workaround is the only approach that worked for me.

Comment: This saved my day! The only workaround. I have tried with build tools 26.0.0 and I got the same issue.

Comment: Any idea how to solve this when included via xml for a menu item (`android:icon=@drawable/icon_name`)?

Comment: @serv-inc use ```app:srcCompat=@drawable/icon_name``` instead

Comment: this worked for me. After a long long time in internet looking for some solutions... This helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I found a rather interesting workaround to this.  If you set the background to a drawable file that contains the xml drawable then the exception/crash goes away.

So create a drawable file that has the following:

```
<selector
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
     android:drawable="@drawable/your_image_here.xml" />
</selector>
```

and put the name of this drawable file as the background...

Answer (score 3):

If it is not working just for Pre-Lollipop, add this in your Activity

```
static {
    AppCompatDelegate.setCompatVectorFromResourcesEnabled(true);
}
```